# Hidden woocommerce out of stock products takes up space

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

I am trying to hide all out of stock products except ones with specific attribute.

I'm using woocommerce_product_is_visible filter for that. Here's my function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_visible', 'my_fn_show_backorders', 10, 2 );
function my_fn_show_backorders( $is_visible, $id ) {
    if ( !is_woocommerce() ) return $is_visible;
    $product = new wC_Product( $id );
    $available = $product->get_attribute('pa_availability');
    $restock = $available == 'Only with restock';
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && ! $restock ) {
        $is_visible = false;
    }
    return $is_visible;
}
```

It works, but problem is - it leaves blank spaces in shop / category view where out of stock products should be. And if I sort by stock status, I get 5 empty pages at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your function would work as you would expect, since it would seem that `$restock` would always return true. Also, `$available` should be `$product->get_attribute('availability')` without the `pa_`

This (below) removes the product(s) from the listing, but doesn't update the "found products" count since it happens after the query.

I don't think you can use `woocommerce_product_query` to query your results, since you're trying to do a tax_query and a meta_query at the same time. It might be better to make your "availability" a post_meta rather than a taxonomy (pa_) so that you can query both in a single swoop.

In the meantime... this answer corrects your errors.  If you want to revise your data structure it might be easier to get the results you want.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_visible', 'my_fn_show_backorders', 10, 2 );
function my_fn_show_backorders( $is_visible, $id ) {
    $product   = wc_get_product( $id );
    $available = $product->get_attribute( 'availability' );
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && ( 'Only with restock' !== $available ) ) {
        $is_visible = false;
    }
    return $is_visible;
}
```